# Bug in Listview. When I roll my list view, the imageview is changing by it self. What was my mistake?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

In my method that getView:

```
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_historico_layout, parent, false);
    }

    DadosHistorico dadosHistorico = (DadosHistorico) getItem(index);

    TextView tvdata = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvData);
    tvdata.setText(dadosHistorico.getData());

    TextView ivstatushistorico = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvStatushistorico);
    ivstatushistorico.setText(dadosHistorico.getStatus());

    TextView tvInternetTitlo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvInternetTitulo);
    tvInternetTitlo.setText(dadosHistorico.getInternet());

    TextView tvLigacaoTitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLigacaoTitulo);
    tvLigacaoTitulo.setText(dadosHistorico.getLigacao());

    TextView tvInternetDescricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvInternetDescricaoHistorico);
    tvInternetDescricao.setText(dadosHistorico.getInternetDescricao());

    TextView tvLigacaiDescricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLigacaoDescricaoHistorico);
    tvLigacaiDescricao.setText(dadosHistorico.getLigacaoDescricao());

    TextView tvComentarioHistorico = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvComentarioHistorico);
    tvComentarioHistorico.setText(dadosHistorico.getComentario());

    final String comentario = tvComentarioHistorico.getText().toString();

    ImageView ivStatusLed = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivStatusLe);


    if(ivstatushistorico.getText().equals("1")){
        ivStatusLed.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_led);    
        ivStatusLed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }    


    ImageView ibComentarioHistorico = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ibComentarioHistorico);

    if(comentario.equals("")){
        ibComentarioHistorico.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }else{
        ibComentarioHistorico.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     }


    ibComentarioHistorico.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Comentário");
            alertDialog.setMessage(comentario);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();


        }
    });


    return view;


    }

    public void addDados(String data, String status, String internet, String internetDescricao, String ligacao, String ligacaoDescricao, String comentario) {
        dados.add(new DadosHistorico(data, status, internet, internetDescricao, ligacao, ligacaoDescricao, comentario));

}
}
```

In this code I change the imageview that is in my list. I receive some data from a database and change the imageview. 
The problem is, when I scroll down the listview and scroll back, the imageview are different, some time is gream_led, and some time the ibComentarioHistorico disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `else` statement:

```
if(ivstatushistorico.getText().equals("1")){
    ivStatusLed.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_led);    
    ivStatusLed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    ivStatusLed.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_default);    
    ivStatusLed.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // or whatever the default is
}
```

Views are reused so unless you tell it what to do if it's not equal to "1" you will see the behaviour you are describing.